# ASP.net 4.5 Membership and Roles add user to role

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

I am using asp.net 4.5 membership provider and roles,

problem is I'm trying to set up the creat user wizard to make the new member a certain role strait out the box.
this is the code I am using.

**Code**

```
 protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roles.AddUsersToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName,"customer");
}
```

}

and the error log is giving me a error that I can not convert string and a best overload match,  is there a easy way around this?

I just need to make it that all new users are customer.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the first parameter in the AddUsersToRole is a string array, hence the name of the method "Users", so try something like this:

```
string[] usersToAdd = new string[] { CreateUserWizard1.UserName };

Roles.AddUsersToRole(usersToAdd,"customer");
```

HTH

Phil